# Height to 0 hover effect under Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover, transition

Hy I have a problem under FF. When I try to use hover on a div to transform height to 0, it just working strangely. Is there a way to make it work like under Chrome?
the code is:

CSS :

```
#square{
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:40%;
    width:11%;
    height:22%;
    background-color:blue;
    transition:height 0.8s linear;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.8s linear;
    -moz-transition:height 0.8s linear;
}

#square:hover{
    height:0%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: Well it kind of looks logical because it happens when you're not hover anymore

Comment: Maybe you can have an invisible div that's on top, and use a sibling selector.

Comment: wrap this into a div and use `#mydiv:hover>#square`

Comment: Yes, brewal is right. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D5GTx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap this into a div, so you keep the `hover` even when the `#square` div is no longer under the pointer :

**CSS**

```
#mydiv {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:40%;
    width:11%;
    height:22%;
}
#mydiv:hover>#square {
    height:0%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JX3x7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hy, 
  Actually when you change the size of the element on hovering (specially decreasing), your mouse pointer falls outside of the boundaries. So it is logical for firefox to do some blinking and it is actually a bug on chrome that does not understand the height changes.
If you don't want to mess with your html structure(adding nested dIVs as the holder of hover element ), the best way is to use javascript (I Prefere jQuery):

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#square').hover(function(){
                   $(this).css('height',0);
                   //or use the following line if you want to hide the element:
                   $(this).hide();
              });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This It will work fine. tell me is this right ans or not.
HTML

```
 <div id="squarebox">
       <div id="square"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#squarebox{
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:40%;
    width:11%;
    height:22%;
}
#squarebox > #square{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    transition:all ease-in-out .3s 0s;
}
#squarebox:hover > #square {
    height:0%;
}
```